# Kendo React grid column on resizing to right or left by mouse dragging showing weird behavior having set the "Resizable" attribute to true

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, web-frontend, kendo-react-ui

Kendo React grid column on resizing/ screeching to right or left by clicking and dragging using mouse showing weird behavior like jumping to uncertain positions having set the "Resizable" attribute to true. I have attached the video of this problem.

[image: 1]

I have updated the kendo react dependencies to version 5.9 and resizable to true but not solving this issue.